# KendoUI Grid Not Updating Data Source

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have three HTML drop downs (not using kendo dropdown because of performance), which after being selected go to my controllers action and posts back to update the grid. The problem is after I make my first selection, every selection after that sets it back to the first selected value, so the new parameter is never passed to my controller.

Here is my view

```
<link href="~/Content/kendo/2014.1.318/kendo.default.min.css" rel=" stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/kendo/2014.1.318/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Kendo")
@Html.Label("AB_ID: ")
@Html.DropDownList("AB_ID", null, "--SELECT--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" })
@Html.Label("AB_TYPE: ")
@Html.DropDownList("AB_TYPE", null, "--SELECT--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" })
@Html.Label("A_DD_ID: ")
@Html.DropDownList("A_DD_ID", null, "--SELECT--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" })


@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
          .Name("Grid")
          .DataSource(data => data
                        .Server()
                        .Read(read => read.Action("Grid_Read", "ASSETs"))
                        .PageSize(10))
          .Pageable()
          .Sortable()
)

<script>
function passData() {
    var param = {};
    param.ab_id = $("#AB_ID").val();
    param.ab_type = $("#AB_TYPE").val();
    param.a_dd_id = $("#A_DD_ID").val();
    return param;
}

$(".dropdown-toggle").on("change", function () {
    var data = passData();
    var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");

    grid.dataSource.read(data); 
});
```

Here is my controller

```
public ActionResult Grid_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string ab_id, string ab_type,
            string a_dd_id)
        {
            IQueryable<ASSET> assets = null;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ab_id) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ab_type) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a_dd_id))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ab_id)
                    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ab_type)
                    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a_dd_id)
                    )
                {
                    assets = db.ASSETs.Join(db.ASSET_BASE,
                        c => c.A_AB_NO,
                        cm => cm.AB_NO, (c, cm) => new { A = c, AB = cm })
                        .Where(c => c.AB.AB_ID == ab_id && c.AB.AB_TYPE == ab_type && c.A.A_DD_ID == a_dd_id)
                        .Select(x => x.A);
                }
                else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ab_id) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ab_type) )
                {
                    assets = db.ASSETs.Join(db.ASSET_BASE,
                        c => c.A_AB_NO,
                        cm => cm.AB_NO, (c, cm) => new { A = c, AB = cm })
                        .Where(c => c.AB.AB_ID == ab_id && c.AB.AB_TYPE == ab_type)
                        .Select(x => x.A);
                }
                else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ab_id) )
                {
                    assets = db.ASSETs.Join(db.ASSET_BASE,
                        c => c.A_AB_NO,
                        cm => cm.AB_NO, (c, cm) => new { A = c, AB = cm })
                        .Where(c => c.AB.AB_ID == ab_id)
                        .Select(x => x.A);

                }
                else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ab_type) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a_dd_id) )
                {
                    assets = db.ASSETs.Join(db.ASSET_BASE,
                        c => c.A_AB_NO,
                        cm => cm.AB_NO, (c, cm) => new { A = c, AB = cm })
                        .Where(c => c.AB.AB_TYPE == ab_type && c.A.A_DD_ID == a_dd_id)
                        .Select(x => x.A);

                }
                else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ab_id) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a_dd_id) )
                {
                    assets = db.ASSETs.Join(db.ASSET_BASE,
                        c => c.A_AB_NO,
                        cm => cm.AB_NO, (c, cm) => new { A = c, AB = cm })
                        .Where(c => c.AB.AB_ID == ab_id && c.A.A_DD_ID == a_dd_id)
                        .Select(x => x.A);

                }
                else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ab_type) )
                {
                    assets = db.ASSETs.Join(db.ASSET_BASE,
                        c => c.A_AB_NO,
                        cm => cm.AB_NO, (c, cm) => new { A = c, AB = cm })
                        .Where(c => c.AB.AB_TYPE == ab_type)
                        .Select(x => x.A);

                }
                else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a_dd_id))
                {
                    assets = db.ASSETs.Join(db.ASSET_BASE,
                        c => c.A_AB_NO,
                        cm => cm.AB_NO, (c, cm) => new {A = c, AB = cm})
                        .Where(c => c.A.A_DD_ID == a_dd_id)
                        .Select(x => x.A);

                }



            }
            if (assets == null)
                assets = db.ASSETs;
            ViewBag.AB_ID = new SelectList(db.ASSET_BASE.Select(x => x.AB_ID).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x));
            ViewBag.AB_TYPE = new SelectList(db.ASSET_BASE.Select(x => x.AB_TYPE).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x));
            ViewBag.A_DD_ID = new SelectList(db.DICTIONARies.Select(x => x.DD_ID).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x));
            return View("Index", assets);
        }
```

I have tried changing the data source with the following but it still does not seem to be updating the data source with my new parameters. I have also tried changing the grid from a server side grid to a client side one with the same results.

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [
        passData()
    ]
});
grid.setDataSource(dataSource);
```

Comment: I think you have to try with `ajax` post and then update your grid.

Comment: Hey,You take `param` array and in that assign it's value so every time it's take first value and set it..so change the scenario and try something different..